# Text boxes not filled with data from URL?

Tags: php, html

I am working on my website, and I am using PHP. I am facing this problem (or maybe not a problem) where I am trying to take data from URL to put them back in the relevant textboxes, for example when someone tries to sign up, and he fails because the passwords don't match. I don't want him to fill the username/email again, I would fill it for him.

This is how the form looks like:

```
<div class="formie">
        <br><table width="350">
        <form action="signup.php" method="POST">
        <h2><u>.: Registration :.</u></h2>
        <br><br>
        <tr>
        <td width="50%"><b>Username</b></td>
        <td width="50%"><input type="text" class="txtbox" name="uid" maxlength="30"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td width="50%"><b>Password</b></td>
        <td width="50%"><input type="password" name="pwd" maxlength="30" class="txtbox"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td width="50%"><b>Confirm Password</b></td>
        <td width="50%"><input type="password" name="repeat_pwd" maxlength="30" class="txtbox"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td width="50%"><b>E-mail Address</b></td>
        <td width="50%"><input type="text" name="emailaddr" maxlength="40" class="txtbox"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td width="50%"><input type="submit" name="signup-btn" value="Register" class="btn"></td>
        <td width="50%"><input type="reset" value="Clear" class="btn"></td>
        </tr>
        </form>
        </table>
    </div>
```

And I am trying to doing this

```
if ($pass !== $passrepeat) {
        header("Location: register.php?error=passnomatch&uid=".$username."&emailaddr=".$email);
        exit();
    }
```

Note that register.php is the form page, and signup.php is just the php where it deals with sql queries and checks and all that.

Any idea why uid=... is not filling out the textboxes ?
Thanks a lot

Comment: You need to set the value for `value` tag of inputs

Comment: You're neither checking for `$_GET['uid']` nor setting a `value="..."` in your inputs

Comment: easier than redirecting (and better than exposing personal data like an email address inside a URL where it can be logged etc) would be to submit the form to the same script where the HTML is located. Validate the data there, and if it's not valid, then you can simply echo the HTML again but with the data pre-populated. Redirection to the next step would only happen if the data is all validated and saved successfully in the database. Either that, or you could redesign it so the form is submitted via AJAX, and therefore the user never leaves the page at all, thus preserving the form & data.

Comment: You can also store the data in a session and read it from there when you reload the form. Or even better, use ajax. Then the page won't be reloaded at all.

Comment: I did it with the `value` tag in the end. And thanks a lot for the tips guys, really appreciate it :)